# Luhn algorithm: find how many numbers are vaild?

Tags: algorithms

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm), the Luhn algorithm or Luhn formula, also known as the "modulus 10" or "mod 10" algorithm, named after its creator, IBM scientist Hans Peter Luhn, is a simple checksum formula used to validate a variety of identification numbers, such as credit card numbers.

The algorithm as follow:

Write down the string: $4634$ $8932$ $1298$ $2767$

Reverse the string: $\color{red}76\color{red}72$ $\color{red}89\color{red}21$ $\color{red}23\color{red}98$ $\color{red}43\color{red}63$

$\color{red}{A=7+7+8+2+2+9+4+6}=45$

Double the even digits: $6*2=12$; $2*2=4$; $9*2=18$; $1*2=2$; $3*2=6$; $8*2=16$; $3*2=6$; $4*2=8$

$B=(1+2)+4+(1+8)+2+6+(1+6)+6+8=45$

$A+B=45+45=90$ -The units digit is $0$, therefore, the string $4634$ $8932$ $1298$ $2767$ is vaild.

Now, I wondered: Suppose 2853 00QP P003 6002 is a valid string, $P$ and $Q$ are digits and $P\le Q$. How many pairs of $P$ and $Q$ are there?

### My attempt:

Reverse the digits: 2006 300P PQ00 3582

$A=2+0+3+0+P+0+3+8=16+P$

Double the even digits:

$0*2=0$; $6*2=12$; $0*2=0$; $P*2=2P$; $Q*2=2Q$; $0*2=0$; $5*2=10$; $5*2=10$; $2*2=4$

The next step is to sum all of its digits, but I am not sure whether $2P$ or $2Q$ is a 2-digits number or not.

Please help me. Thank you very much.

Comment: Reversing doesn't seem to get you much.  It might be easiest to consider different cases for $P$ and $Q$.  If they're less than 5, then $2P$ and $2Q$ are single digits; otherwise, the first digit is 1 and the second digit is $2P-10$ and $2Q-10$.

Comment: Seems that in reversing the above string, a typo appeared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's continue the calculation, skipping the parts where you need to know whether P and Q are 2-digit numbers:

$$A + B = (16 + P) + ((\text{digit sum of } 2P) + (\text{digit sum of } 2Q) + 9)$$
$$= 25 + P + (\text{digit sum of } 2P) + (\text{digit sum of } 2Q).$$

The next step could simply be to go through all possible values of $P$ and $Q$ and see whether the final result has ones digit $0$. You could either just go through all 100 cases, or separate everything into four groups cases depending on whether $P$ or $Q$ are at least $5$.

However, a much better choice would be to go through all possible values of $P$, then determine for which $Q$ the result has ones digit $0$.

In fact, since you can solve for $(\text{digit sum of } 2Q)$, there's exactly one valid value of $(\text{digit sum of } 2Q)$ for every value of $P$. Now for each value of $(\text{digit sum of } 2Q)$ there's exactly one $Q$ producing that value. Now you just need to check whether $P \leq Q$ for each of the $10$ possible values of $P$.